# Creating a test site for a current IIS site?

Tags: iis, web-server, asp

I am asked to edit the website of a company I started working for.

The directions I was given to setup Dreamweaver involve uploading directly to the live site.  I wanted to create a test site to upload documents so I can preview the changes before putting them to the live site.

I created a test site in IIS on the server hosting the website.  I made sure its properties mirrored the actual site.  I then copied all the files from the actual sites directory and placed them in the test sites directory.

The problem is that if I visit actual/page.asp it displays fine yet if I visit test/page.asp I get an active server page error.

It is the same .asp page in both directories.  What should I be looking for to make this work?

Comment: I suggest you put a plain "hello world" html file in the test site and make it work, then get ASP going.

Comment: That does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would **not** do my testing on the same box as production.  The chances of an error that screw up the live site are too high.

The easiest solution is to install IIS on your development box.  If you manage the firewall you can add NAT to send the same site on another port (:888?) to your box on port 80 so that external testing can happen.

Another (if the site is basic) is to use a free asp.net hosting service (such as [this](http://www.asphost4free.com/)).

Comment: The actual site and the test site do not share the same directory.  So when I upload to the test site I am only changing files within the test site's directory.  How could this affect the actual site?

Comment: Oh, say, by erroneously changing the configuration of the live site while trying to get the test site working.  Or by uploading accidentally to the live folder.  Or by crashing the server accidentally through bad code.  And so on ...

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error?  What version of IIS are you using?  If it is 6 or 7, did you make sure to allow ASP applications to run in the site you created?